# Use of Foldcolumns in Vim

Tags: folding

I never thought of the use of foldcolumns in vim. There are `-` and `+` signs to indicate foldable or folded parts of the code, that I understand. But what about the numbers inside the cosecutive `-` signs? If I increase foldcolumn width the numbers take another form. I learned that the numbers help to identify foldable parts properly. Can someone explain its use?

I read `foldcolumn.txt`, `folding.txt` and `foldmethods.txt` and I still don't understand foldcolumns!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They indicate folds and their nesting levels:

A `+` plus symbol marks a closed fold, and a `-` minus marks the first line of an open fold.

If `foldcolumn` is high enough (i.e. greater that the number of open nested folds currently being displayed), then each nested open fold will be preceded by a bar character `|`, so if you have 3 nested open folds you will see a display something like this:

```
     not in a fold
-    start of fold 1
|    inside fold 1
|-   start of fold 2
||   inside fold 2
||-  start of fold 3
|||  inside fold 3
|||+ closed fold 4
|||  inside fold 3
|||  end of fold 3
||   inside fold 2
||   end of fold 2
|    inside fold 1
|    end of fold 1
     not in a fold
```

However, if you decrease the size of `foldcolumn` so there is no longer enough room to use this style of display), then nested bar characters will be replaced with digits as necessary:

e.g., with the example above, if you execute `:set foldcolumn=3`, there is not enough room for three nested `|` characters *and* a `+` sign, so numbers are used instead as necessary:

```
     not in a fold
-    start of fold 1
|    inside fold 1
|-   start of fold 2
||   inside fold 2
2-  start of fold 3
23  inside fold 3
23+ closed fold 4
23  inside fold 3
23  end of fold 3
||   inside fold 2
||   end of fold 2
|    inside fold 1
|    end of fold 1
     not in a fold
```

With  `foldcolumn=1` the number of `|` characters that can be displayed is even more restricted:

```
  not in a fold
- start of fold 1
| inside fold 1
- start of fold 2
2 inside fold 2
- start of fold 3
3 inside fold 3
+ closed fold 4
3 inside fold 3
3 end of fold 3
2 inside fold 2
2 end of fold 2
| inside fold 1
| end of fold 1
  not in a fold
```